# How to access a property inside an object and use in another method? javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I need to create a method to return a customers name and bank account value like so:

```
*bank.printAccount('Sheldon'); // this should print 'Sheldon account is 0'*
```

However I am struggling to find out how to access the property **customers** to use in a method ****printAccount****. Currently I have this:

```
class Bank {
    constructor(){
        this.customers = {};
    }
  
  }
  Bank.prototype.addCustomer = function(customer){
       this.customers[customer] = 0;

  }
  Bank.prototype.printAccount = function(){
  

  };
  var bank = new Bank();
  bank.addCustomer('Sheldon');
  bank.addCustomer('Bob');
```

Comment: There's no need to use `.prototype` when using `class`

Comment: yes I read that but every time I try to use it without prototype with a dot or square brackets I keep receiving and error :TypeError: bank.addCustomer is not a function. (In 'bank.addCustomer('Sheldon')', 'bank.addCustomer' is undefined). But either way I still can't access the property from customers to use in printAccount method.

Comment: Maybe `this.addCustomer()`?

Comment: I tried this already. It also throws an error when you place it in the parameters of the method

Comment: What's that error? Maybe it's easier to solve.

Comment: SyntaxError: Cannot use the keyword 'this' as a parameter name. Same for both dot or square brackets

Comment: You should add `this.account = 0` to the `constructor`. Then make a setter and getter since this process requires the class to use it's own properties.

Comment: Post your code from when you tried `this.addCustomer()`. You shouldn't be using `this` as a parameter name in that case.

Comment: ```class Bank {
    constructor(){
        this.customers = {};
    }
  
  }
  Bank.prototype.addCustomer = function(customer){
       this.customers[customer] = 0;

  }
  Bank.prototype.printAccount = function(this.addCustomer()){
  

  }
  var bank = new Bank();
  bank.addCustomer('Sheldon');
  bank.addCustomer('Bob');                   ```

Comment: I'm not understanding why you're passing a function as a parameter to `printAccount()`... If you are printing an account, shouldn't the customer already exist?

Comment: the customers exist inside the empty object in the constructor this.customers{}. Customers are stored there from the addCustomer method. But I need to access the specific customer and value  when I call their name in the printAccount method.

Comment: "*I am struggling to find out how to access the property `customers`*" - uh, you can access it in `printAccount` in exactly the same way as you did in `addCustomer`: `this.customers[customer]`.

Comment: @user19051554 ... 1/2 ... the OP should consider [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)ing new customer items into a *customers* array or even better [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set)ting such items at a *customers* [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance.

Comment: @user19051554 ... 2/2 ... Also, since *class* syntax is used the [prototype methods preferably should be implemented within the class body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#prototype_methods).

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
class Bank {
  constructor() {
      this.customers = {};
  }
}
Bank.prototype.addCustomer = function(customer) {
     this.customers[customer] = 0;
}
Bank.prototype.printAccount = function(customer) {
     console.log(this.customers[customer])
};

var bank = new Bank();
bank.addCustomer('Sheldon');
bank.addCustomer('Bob');
bank.printAccount('Sheldon');
bank.printAccount('Bob');
```

You probably will need to add edge cases in `printAccount()` such as to check  whether the customer exists or not.

**Edit:** Removed doubled initialization of `customers`.

Comment: thanks Jishan! your answer helped me! :)